# requirejs load json from api or from static file

Tags: angularjs, json, requirejs

I'm loading json file from api call (API/GetDynamicLayout).

```
define([
    'angular',
    'app',
    'json!API/GetDynamicLayout'
],
function (angular, app, layoutJSON) {
'use strict';
app.provider("layoutJSON", 
    [function () {
        this.value = layoutJSON;
        this.$get = function () {
            return {
                get: function () {
                    return layoutJSON;
                }
            }
        }
    }]);

});
```

My API will return `401` response if the user is not authenticate.
How can I create condition that load static JSON file if the user is not logged in?

Comment: Where is your XHR request?

Comment: json!API/GetDynamicLayout is requirejs syntax for get request. the server returns json.